# Power lines and cars

Tags: electricity

A live, active power line fell on the hood of my car. I was told to turn on my car and back away.  Was this the proper advice?

Comment: An essential question is whether you have already been in your car when this happened. If not, then touching your car might be dangerous. If yes, then I don't see a problem

Comment: Since you're still alive, the advice wasn't *that* bad...

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.